# For loop in R list

Tags: r, for-loop

I am excepting the below code to do the following:
- **if the current value is smaller then the previous one, change it with the previous one.**

But, as you already guessed, it doesn't behave this way.
When I print i between iterations, I can see that the transformations are done, but they are not implemented in the drop_rate list.

Any suggestions how to upgrade this code so changes are made in the list?

```
drop_rate<-list(
x1=c(0.0000000,0.2666667,0.3466667,0.4666667,0.3866667,0.7333333),
x2=c(0.0000000,0.3076923,0.4102564,0.5000000,0.4230769,0.7307692),
x3=c(0.0000000,0.2763158,0.3815789,0.4736842,0.4210526,0.7368421),
x4=c(0.0000000,0.2987013,0.3896104,0.5064935,0.4285714,0.7402597),
x5=c(0.0000000,0.3116883,0.4025974,0.5064935,0.4285714,0.7272727))

for (i in drop_rate){
  if (i[1]>i[2]){i[2]=i[1]}
  if (i[2]>i[3]){i[3]=i[2]}
  if (i[3]>i[4]){i[4]=i[3]}
  print(i)
  if (i[4]>i[5]){i[5]=i[4]}
  print(i)
  if (i[5]>i[6]){i[6]=i[5]}
}
```

Expected outpot (what should change is delimited with **):

```
0.0000000,0.2666667,0.3466667,0.4666667,**0.4666667**,0.7333333
0.0000000,0.3076923,0.4102564,0.5000000,**0.5000000**,0.7307692
0.0000000,0.2763158,0.3815789,0.4736842,**0.4736842**,0.7368421
0.0000000,0.2987013,0.3896104,0.5064935,**0.5064935**,0.7402597
0.0000000,0.3116883,0.4025974,0.5064935,**0.5064935**,0.7272727
```

Comment: You need `[[` instead of `[`.  also `if/else` works on a single element i.e. of length 1.  I guess you may need to check if all elements are greater than ?

Comment: Put them everywhere, this is what i get: Error in if (i[[1]] > i[[2]]) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: Nevermind, solved the error. But it's still not doing the transformations.

Comment: Can you check my solution below with `pmin` and `Map`.  If you had showed the expected output, it would be easier to crosscheck

Comment: I've added an expected output. Hope it's more clear now. You're solution works but not in the way I wanted to. Just adding [[ makes no changes.

Comment: The comparisons are just within-list, not between.

Comment: yes, got it. please check my updated output with `cummax`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is that `[` extraction is still a `list` with `length` one.  So, we need to do `[[`.  Also, `if/else` is not vectorized. Based on the updated OP's post, we need to check within each `list` elements.  Here, if we stick with `if/else`, then a nested `for` loop is needed

```
for(i in seq_along(drop_rate)){
     tmp <- drop_rate[[i]]
     for(j  in 2:length(tmp)) {
          if(tmp[j-1] > tmp[j]) {
              tmp[j] <- tmp[j-1]
          }
         }
        drop_rate[[i]] <- tmp 


       }
```

---

We can use `cummax`

```
drop_rate <- lapply(drop_rate, cummax)
drop_rate
#$x1
#[1] 0.0000000 0.2666667 0.3466667 0.4666667 0.4666667 0.7333333

#$x2
#[1] 0.0000000 0.3076923 0.4102564 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.7307692

#$x3
#[1] 0.0000000 0.2763158 0.3815789 0.4736842 0.4736842 0.7368421

#$x4
#[1] 0.0000000 0.2987013 0.3896104 0.5064935 0.5064935 0.7402597

#$x5
#[1] 0.0000000 0.3116883 0.4025974 0.5064935 0.5064935 0.7272727
```

Comment: Works like a charm. And a lot more simpler. Thank you